# How to change image of each tab item when clicked and hover?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, tabs

[how to change yellow image to blue image in tabs when clicked and hover by jquery or css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6nDK.jpg)

[image]

Comment: You need to show us enough code to make it possible to help. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS filter properties to do this with CSS.

```
img:hover {filter: hue-rotate(165deg);}
```

Adjust hue-rotate value if needed.